# dask processes not terminating for some reason

Tags: python, dask

My dask child processes are not terminating for some reason when I set `num_workers` to be large (like 10). My job is running on a 100+ core machine and running code similar to word count on a 50GB file. The stacktrace looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process PoolWorker-9:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process PoolWorker-6:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Process PoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process PoolWorker-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Process PoolWorker-2:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
Process PoolWorker-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Process PoolWorker-10:
    task = get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 374, in get
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self.run()
    self.run()
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    racquire()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
KeyboardInterrupt
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 374, in get
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 374, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 374, in get
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    racquire()
    return recv()
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 374, in get
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 374, in get
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
    self.run()
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
```

(similarly for other workers)

Any idea what is going on? The same job running on a smaller input (100MB) always terminate.

Comment: This has the same issue as last time you asked this. We need a [mcve].

Comment: @MorganThrapp I'm not seeing a previous question that this repeats.  Can you link to the original?  It looks like this user only has one other question and that one is distinct from this one.

That being said, minimal complete verifiable examples are always appreciated and enable the supply of much better answers.

Comment: @MRocklin I believe they deleted it. I remember seeing this exact question from them earlier today.

Comment: @pete-danzig can you give more information on how you produce this failure?  Currently on a KeyboardInterrupt we close down the pool.  I'll need more information to properly diagnose what's going on.